# Logging all mouse movement in Qt

Tags: c++, windows, qt, winapi, event-handling

i try to make a little pointing task in C++. I created the GUI with Qt. In the application i replace the cursor with a self drawn point on the QWidget. So later i can manipulate the cursor movement. On every Mouseevent i do an update. The problem is, that it is super important to log all mouse movement. Even the RawInputData of the mouse, so need the native Windows events. When i use the native event handlers from Qt the problem is, that my thread is blocked while updating the Widget. So tried to seperate the event handling and the drawing in two different threads. But this seems to be very difficulty. So my second idea was to create a invisible windows window, which catches all the information and then i handle them over to Qt. But i'm not able to make such a windows window. At the moment mine does not receive any messages. Later it should run in the background.

My Qt attempt:

```
bool Widget::nativeEvent(const QByteArray &eventType, void *message, long *result) {
    MSG *msg = (MSG*)message;
    switch(msg->message)
    {
    case WM_INPUT: {

            POINT lpPoint;
            GetCursorPos(&lpPoint);
            xCursor = lpPoint.x;
            yCursor = lpPoint.y;
            //std::cerr << "Cursor: X: " << lpPoint.x << " || Y: " << lpPoint.y << std::endl;

            UINT dwSize;

            GetRawInputData((HRAWINPUT)msg->lParam, RID_INPUT, NULL, &dwSize,
                            sizeof(RAWINPUTHEADER));
            LPBYTE lpb = new BYTE[dwSize];
            if (lpb == NULL)
            {
                return 0;
            }

            if (GetRawInputData((HRAWINPUT)msg->lParam, RID_INPUT, lpb, &dwSize,
                 sizeof(RAWINPUTHEADER)) != dwSize )
                 OutputDebugString (TEXT("GetRawInputData does not return correct size !\n"));

            RAWINPUT* raw = (RAWINPUT*)lpb;
            if(raw->header.dwType == RIM_TYPEMOUSE) {
                //std::cerr << "RAW: X: " << raw->data.mouse.lLastX << " || Y: " << raw->data.mouse.lLastY << std::endl;
            }

            delete[] lpb;

            update();

            return false;

        }


    default:{
        //std::cerr << "other Message" << std::endl;
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

And my message window:

```
    LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam){
    std::cerr << "callback" << std::endl;
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    const char CLASS_NAME[]  = "Sample Window Class";

    WNDCLASS wc = { };

    wc.lpfnWndProc   = WindowProc;
    wc.hInstance     = GetModuleHandle(NULL);
    wc.lpszClassName = CLASS_NAME;

    RegisterClass(&wc);

    // Create the window.

    HWND hwnd = CreateWindowEx(
            0,                              // Optional window styles.
            CLASS_NAME,                     // Window class
            "Learn to Program Windows",    // Window text
            WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,            // Window style

            // Size and position
            CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,

            HWND_MESSAGE,       // Parent window
            NULL,       // Menu
            GetModuleHandle(NULL),  // Instance handle
            NULL        // Additional application data
    );

    if (hwnd == NULL)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    MSG msg;
    while (GetMessage(&msg, hwnd, 0 ,0)) {
        std::cerr << "Message received!" << std::endl;
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
}
```

I would be glad about any input or ideas.

Comment: The easy fix: Stop `update()`-ing your widget from your input processing. That said, you cannot hope to reliably handle native events in a Qt application, that depend on data attached to the message (in this case the raw input data referenced through `lParam`). Qt will, under some conditions, resort to recording and replaying input messages, thereby losing all data attached to messages. Things like `GetMessageTime`, `GetMessageExtraInfo`, or `GetRawInputData` will fail with replayed (aka fake) messages.

Comment: You create a message-only window which can't receive all kind of messages. It receives only messages sent or posted specifically to it. Refer to [Raymond's blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20171218-00/?p=97595).